# ios delegate and scrollView Invalid

Tags: ios, delegates, scrollview, call

I write this in a `UIViewController` but the things in the `menuVC` like `delegate` and `scrollView` doesn't work anymore, what happened

```
MuneScrollViewViewController *muneVC =[[MuneScrollViewViewController alloc]init]; 
muneVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30); 
[self.view addSubview:muneVC.view];
```

Comment: Your code gives us no idea as to what went wrong. There is nothing wrong with these 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that menuVC is dealocated, and only its view exist on screen, that may be the problem why delegates did not work. You can make the menuVC a strong property on your view controller, so it will not be dealocated when your method is finished.

Or better set your menuVC as child controller

```
self.addChildViewController(menuVC)
```

Comment: thanks，after reading your advice，i find my understanding of using viewController in viewController is not right,very nice of you